# bootstrap form-horizontal right align labels

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

If it possible to get right-align labels in twitter bootstrap form-horizontal?

So in this example of horizontal form http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms
letter "E" in "Email" will be over letter "P" in "Password".

Comment: Bad UI to left align, IMO: http://css-tricks.com/label-placement-on-forms/

Answer (score 24):

Actually, they are right aligned as it is. I think you want to *left* align them (so P is over E) if I understand correctly. If so, you can try this:

```
.form-horizontal .control-label {
    text-align: left;
}
```

(it's "text-align: right;" by default in bootstrap.css)